# KSH : cp only based on file size

Tags: ksh, cp, size

I would like to write a small script copying from a directory A to directory B all the files with the `.log` extension.
So in my directory A, I've :

```
ls : 
a.log
b.log
c.log
```

Here is the pseudo-code I would like to implement :

```
foreach *.log x do :
    if [stat -c %s pk_copylogs < 10485760]; then 
          cp  A/x  B/x       
    else
          read vANSWER?" >> File x is bigger than 10 MB, would you like to copy it anyway ? Type YES or NO : "
          if [ $vANSWER = "YES"]; then
              cp A/x B/x
          fi
    fi
```

My main problem here, is to find a way to implement my `foreach *.log`. How can I do that ?

Comment: Why don't you use rsync?

Comment: It looks like cp -i will copy them, and interactively prompting only to overwrite. In my case, it's both for overwriting and writing.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in two commands:

```
find A -name "*.log" -size -10485760c -exec cp {} B/ +
find A -name "*.log" -size +10485760c -exec cp -i {} B/ +
```

The first finds files smaller than 10485760 and copies indiscriminately. The second finds files larger than 10485760 and copies interactively, prompting for each copy.

Put them into a shell script or function so that you can execute it with a single command, if you like.

Comment: Actually I tried : 

find . -name "*.log" -size +10485760c -exec cp -i {} $3/$2/ \;


--> didn't work, copy file with size higher than 10 mb without asking.

Looking into man page, I guess I've forget something here